# Excel - Find Strings in Column That Do Not Equal Array of Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a column of data. I want to find all the values that do not equal any values from an array, one by one.

I tried defining a named value which was an array like this

`={"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"}`

..and so on.

Which excel functions can I use to find values that are not contained in the array.

And why is the function not iterating through the array? It's only testing the first index.

I tried this:
`{=NOT(X8=NamedValue)}`

And `=MATCH(NamedValue, X3,0)`

Both only test the first value in the array.

Comment: Should be clear that the values are strings.

Comment: It looks like the easiest way to do this would be to define an array constant and then pass that into the ```lookup_value``` though I still can't get excel to iterate past the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Excel's `MATCH()` function for this purpose. Supply `0` to the `match_type` parameter. More information can be found on [this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php).

**Examples of usage:**

Pass hard-coded list of values to the formula:

```
=MATCH("dfs", {"erw","sad","dfs"}, 0)
```

Pass cell range to the formula:

```
=MATCH("dfs", C1:C15, 0)
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting the same result as my test.

```=MATCH(NamedValue, X3,0)```

Comment: I found this article as well: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx

But neither mentions passing in an array as the ```lookup_value```

Comment: I just checked and `=MATCH("def", {"abc","def","ghi"}, 0)` correctly returns `2` for me.

Comment: My understanding is that the first parameter, in this case ```"def"``` is the lookup_value, which should be the array of values I want to return true for. 

Then the ```lookup_array``` should be the complete list of values, returning false for any string that isn't in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Assume column A is your list of "good values", column B is list of all values.

A        B
value2  value1
value3  value2
value4  value3
        value4
        value5
Place the following formula in C1, and copy down

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)),0,1)
```

Which will place a "1" in the the rows where there is a match, and false otherwise.